# Integrating Jest runner with react app created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, flowtype

I am trying to integrate [Jest flow runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-runner-flowtype) with my app created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) as I want to run my flow type checks along with the test cases.

I followed the steps given in the [Jest platforms video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtjyeojAOBs) and added:-

```
{
  "jest": {
     "runner": "jest-runner-flowtype"
   }
}
```

in my `package.json` but got this message:-

```
Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest 
options:

 • collectCoverageFrom
 • coverageReporters
 • coverageThreshold
 • snapshotSerializers.

 These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

 • runner

 If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.
```

Is there a way to use both `jest flow runner` & `test runner` at the same time with jest?

I read on [create-react-app testing guide](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#running-tests) but couldn't find a way to add one runner.

Update:

I tried ejecting from the `create-react-app` and added projects option:-

```
 "projects": [
    {
      "displayName": "flow",
      "runner": "jest-runner-flowtype",
      "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/**/*.js"]
    }
  ]
```

and tried running `yarn jest --env=jsdom` still no flow types are errors are being displayed.

Comment: *I followed the steps given in the Jest platforms video but create-react-app doesn't allow to add runner setting for jest.* - what exactly did you do and what does 'doesn't allow' mean? Users don't have to watch the whole video to understand your case.

Comment: @estus thanks for pointing, updated the information.

Comment: *If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup* - that's it.

Comment: @estus tried that too but still no flow errors when running `yarn flow` giving the warnings.